# PHP Find all occurences of a whole word from a text

Tags: php, text, words

Here is my problem, I have a text in PHP :

```
$text = "Car is going with 10 meters/second"

$find = array("meters","meters/second");
```

now when I do this :

```
 foreach ($find as $f)
   {
     $count = substr_count($text,$f);
    }
```

The output is :

```
meters -> 1
meters/second -> 1
```

Normally I consider meters/second as a whole word, so meters shouldn't be counted, only meters/second since no space seperates them

Thus What I Expect :

```
meters -> 0
meters/second -> 1
```

Comment: why should it be 0 for `meters`? it does appear in text...

Comment: `meters` is also there. Then why 0 for it?

Comment: You're doing it with substr. if you're asking for finding only whole word, please a bit search :)

Comment: Normally I consider meters/second as a whole word, so meters shouldn't be counted, only meters/second since no space seperates them

Comment: @FaouziNikolaic stop searching for `meters` then...

Comment: @Guillaume I have too, since I want to get the meters if only meters is specified for example : Car is going with 10 meters/second for a distance of 300 meters, then I want meters -> 1 , meters/second -> 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression, `\b` won't work because `/` is a word boundary, but something like that should work:

```
preg_match_all(",meters([^/]|$),", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: this works great only with meters it returns 0, but for seconds alone it returns 1. while also for seconds alone it should be 0

Answer (score 0):

```
$exists = preg_match("/\bmeters\b/", $text) ;
```

`\b` stands for word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you will have to use [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Something like:

```
$text = "Car is going with 10 meters/second";
$find = array("/\bmeters\b/", "/\bmeters\/second\b/");

foreach($find as $f) {
    print(preg_match_all($f, $text));
}
```

Comment: It does work because it is escaped with the \. I tested it and it got the results which the OP desired.